# Scraping HREF Links contained within a Table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I've been bouncing around a ton of similar questions, but nothing that seems to fix the issue... I've set this up (with help) to scrape the HREF tags from a different `URL`.

I'm trying to now take the `HREF` links in the "Result" column from [this URL](https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=2&stats_player_seq=-100).

[here](https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=2&stats_player_seq=-100)

The script doesn't seem to be working like it did for other sites.

The table is an `HTML` element, but no matter how I tweak my script, I can't retrieve anything except a blank result.

Could someone explain to me why this is the case? I'm watching many YouTube videos trying to understand, but this just doesn't make sense to me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    profiles = []
    urls = [
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=6&stats_player_seq=-100'
    
    
    ]
    for url in urls:
        req = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
        for profile in soup.find_all('a'):
    
            profile = profile.get('href')
    
            profiles.append(profile)
    
    print(profiles)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17'}

r = requests.get('https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=6&stats_player_seq=-100', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for x in soup.select('a'):
    print(x.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Main issue in that case is that you miss to send a [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), cause some sites, regardless of whether it is a good idea, use this as base to decide that you are a bot and do not or only specific content.

So minimum is to provide some of that infromation while making your request:

```
req = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

Also take a closer look to your selection. Assuming you like to get the team links only you should adjust it, I used `css selectors`:

```
for profile in soup.select('table a[href^="/team/"]'):
```

It also needs concating the baseUrl to the extracted values:

```
profile = 'https://stats.ncaa.org'+profile.get('href')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

profiles = []
urls = ['https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=6&stats_player_seq=-100']

for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for profile in soup.select('table a[href^="/team/"]'):
        profile = 'https://stats.ncaa.org'+profile.get('href')
        profiles.append(profile)

print(profiles)
```